# Can the direct sum of a real algebra be embedded into itself?

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, differential-geometry, operator-algebras

> Does there exist a real algebra $A$ which admits an **injective $A$-module homomorphism** $A^n\to A$, where the image has co-dimension $1$ (and $n$ is strictly greater than $1$)?

I am asking for $n>1$, as for $n=1$ the map $C^\infty(\Bbb R)\to C^\infty(\Bbb R)$, $f\mapsto x\cdot f$ gives us an example where it does work.

This obviously cannot happen with any finite-dimensional algebras. With dimension I refer to the dimension of the algebra as a real vector space.

I am led to this question in an exercise, in which I would like to show that the ideal of those functions that vanish on a sub-manifold is not locally free as a $C^\infty$ module (in the case that the sub-manifold has co-dimension $>1$). This gives the question a slight differential geometry flavour.

Comment: No time to write it up, but I would think about the set 
$X=\{\frac{1}{n} :n\in\mathbb N\}$
and consider $A=C_0(X)$.

Comment: I think it cannot work with your example. Let $f$ be the function that takes value $2$ on point $1$ and $0$ on other points. Now multiplication with $f$ on $C_0(X)^n$ has an $n$-dimensional eigenspace to the eigenvalue $2$, but the eigenspace is only $1$-dimensional on $C_0(X)$. So if $\varphi: C_0(X)^n\to C_0(X)$ we have $\varphi( f v) = f \varphi(v)$ since it is supposed to be module homomorphism, this means that the $n$-dimensional eigenspace gets compressed into the $1$-dimensional one. This contradicts the desired injectivity.

Comment: This argument extends whenever $A$ can be written as $A=B\oplus C$, where $B$ is a finite-dimensional sub-algebra and $C$ a complementary sub-algebra. This should rule out any $C(X)$ example where $X$ has an isolated point.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I was thinking you wanted an algebra homomorphism.

Comment: In part the title is at fault, as it does not specify the important $A$-module aspect of the embedding, but I was not sure how construct an attractive looking title for this question that describes it accurately :)

Comment: @s.harp why does it rule out for $C(X)$ where $X$has an isolated point?

Comment: @mathrookie replace $f$ with the function that is $2$ on the isolated point and $0$ elsewhere, then the argument works exactly as before.

Answer (score 2):

If such a module-homomorphism exists for certain $n$, then $A$ has in particular an ideal isomorphic to $A^n$.

So a counterexample, for all $n$ simultaneously, will be given by a simple infinite-dimensional algebra. There are many of these. I'm no algebraist, so I don't have maybe easier examples at hand. But any simple unital Banach algebra is algebraically simple. In particular any unital simple C$^*$-algebra (like $\mathcal O_2$, or $C_r^*(\mathbb F_2)$, or UHF$(2^\infty)$, among many) are counterexamples.

Comment: I think you are answering the converse question here, ie whether examples exist where there is no such map. I'm trying to see whether such a map is impossible in general.

Comment: I see. It look to me that you should rephrase your question, then. Instead of "suppose $A$ is such and such", you should say that you are looking for such $A$. the requirement that the embedding is a module homomorphism seems like a very strong requirement, but I don't have neither an example nor a proof.

Comment: I will rewrite it, the formulation is slightly awkward because I'm not looking for an $A$ that fulfils these requirements, but rather believe that no such $A$ can exist.